# Remove dynamic string from another string PHP (regex)

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove this string

```
page=x
```

`x` being a dynamic string (should be a number but can be anything)

from another string, for example

```
url/?filter=value&page=2&filter2=value
```

but it can also be:

```
url/?page=2
```

So, these are the cases as examples

```
1. url/?page=2&filter=value
2. url/?page=2
3. url/?filter=value&page=2
4. url/?filter=value&page=2&filter2=value
```

And they should return:

```
1. url/?filter=value
2. url/
3. url/?filter=value
4. url/?filter=value&filter2=value
```

How can I do that with regex?

Comment: That made it, answer it so I can accept it man, thanks!

Comment: Okay, moved it to an answer. Also made a couple alterations which should perform better.

Comment: Try this `(&)?page=\d+(?(?=\1)|(?(?=&)&))|\?page=\d+$`. [Link](https://regex101.com/r/VUD9ve/1)

Comment: thanks but I went with Chris answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said:

```
[?&]page=[^&]+
```

works for you. This will look for an `?` or `&` then `page=` and anything after it until an `&`. A bit longer answer though is:

```
echo rtrim(preg_replace('/([?&])page=[^&]*&?/', '$1', $string), '&?')
```

which will correctly handle the intro and ending parameter cases.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/SupbH